# PHP error when using simple file upload script: failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Tags: php, apache, centos

I'm a PHP n00b but followed the instructions as per this excellent tut:

[PHP Tizag file upload tutorial](http://www.tizag.com/phpT/fileupload.php)

However, whilst this worked perfectly on my Mac (OSX 10.8) running the default built-in Apache, it fails and doesn't work on a CentOS 6 box. Looking through the Apache logs I get this:

```
failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

The permissions have been set to **777** on the "uploads" folder which is in the root of **/var/www/html**  (on the mac it's /Library/Webserver/Documents)

```
[Tue Apr 30 13:05:11 2013] [error] [client (My IP Address)] PHP Warning:  move_uploaded_file(uploads/Today notes.txt): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/html/test/uploads3.php on line 8, referer: ht*p://serverip.myserver.com/test/form4.html

[Tue Apr 30 13:05:11 2013] [error] [client (my IP address)] PHP Warning:  move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move '/tmp/phpc8AGo8' to 'uploads/Today notes.txt' in /var/www/html/test/uploads3.php on line 8, referer: ht*p://serverip.myserver.com/test/form4.html
```

Am I missing some setting in PHP or Apache to enable this to work properly?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show the PHP code used

Comment: If you have a problem with a Tizag tutorial, please contact Tizag for support. And yes, as long as you get errors, you are missing something. To find out what, read the error messages and try to understand them.

Comment: Remember case sensitivity when passsing your file path, easy to forget that macs are case insensitive, where cent os will be case sensitive.

Comment: One often runs into this error, and to quickly troubleshoot it, follow these steps : http://stackoverflow.com/a/36577021/2873507

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your question the `uploads` folder is in `/var/www/html`, however going by the error message it is trying to upload into `/var/www/html/test/uploads` which doesn't exist

Either you need to fix the code to upload to the correct path, or you need to create an uploads directory in the test directory

Comment: Thanks, you were right here, although the problem runs deeper than this as it still isn't working via curl which is what I'm actually attempting.  I'd moved things into the temp directory during troubleshooting.  I may have to post a new question to avoid confusion.

Comment: There is now a troubleshooting checklist for this frequent error here : stackoverflow.com/a/36577021/2873507

Answer (score 0):

Please consult the documentation of your operating system. CentOS 6 has additional security configuration that might prevent PHP from accessing the tmp folder.

Allow that folder for access for Apache HTTPD (or change the temporary upload path to a folder Apache HTTPD is allowed access to by SELinux configuration). Also audit the SELinux log to find out what setting exactly prevents access to the directory.

E.g. if you're not running PHP as Apache Module, you might need to allow other processes (e.g. PHP (F)CGI binaries) protected file-system resources.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will resolve your issue

first check  if folder exist, if not create it as bellow

```
if(!is_dir('uploads/Today')){
   mkdir("uploads/Today", 0755);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post, but like many people, nothing works that people suggest with this problem. However, I remembered a problem I had with something else years ago, and it ends up that it affects this situation also.

The problem was SELinux and you have to configure it to allow read/write:
[Centos 7 / Apache / PHP - mkdir(): Permission denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28856148/centos-7-apache-php-mkdir-permission-denied)

Solution:

**chcon -R -t httpd_sys_content_t /var/www/**

**chcon -R -t httpd_sys_content_rw_t /var/www/html/**

If all else fails for you, try this solution.

Best of luck!